# How is the Jacobian linked to the determinant of a transformation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, determinant

I need to show that

if $(X,Y,Z)^T = A(x,y,z)^T$ then

$\dfrac{\partial(X,Y,Z)}{\partial(x,y,z)} = \det(A)$

I sort of understand the link between change in volume and Jacobians and determinants but I have no idea how to show this.

Any hints would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: take a look [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Volume_and_Jacobian_determinant ]

Answer (score 0):

For any linear function $L:{\Bbb R}^n\longrightarrow{\Bbb R}^n$ and any ${\bf x}\in{\Bbb R}^n$:
$$DL({\bf x})=L:{\Bbb R}^n\longrightarrow{\Bbb R}^n,$$
and by definition Jacobian $=\det DL({\bf x})=\det L$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what is $D$ here?

Comment: Differential, the matrix of partial derivatives.